# Diccionario en python me devuelve None

Tags: python

estoy aprendiendo Python y he estado trabajando en algunos ejercicios. Sin embargo, al probar mi código, he notado que siempre obtengo 'None' como resultado. El objetivo es ingresar nombres de estudiantes y sus respectivas notas, calcular el promedio y almacenar todo en un diccionario. El problema parece estar en la parte donde calculo el promedio, ya que siempre me devuelve 'None'. Aquí está mi código:

```
estudiantes = {}
notas = []

nombre = None
promedioMayor = None
promedioMenor = None

def ingresar_nombre():
    global nombre
    nombre = input("Ingrese el nombre del estudiante: ")

def ingresar_nota():
    global nombre
    global notas
    letra = "S"
    while letra != "Q":
        nota = input(f"Ingrese las notas del estudiante {nombre} (ingrese \'Q\' para finalizar): ")
        if nota.isdigit():
            nota = int(nota)
            notas.append(nota)
        else:
            letra = 'Q'

def ingresar_estudiante():
    letra = "S"
    while letra == "S":
        ingresar_nombre()
        notas.clear()
        ingresar_nota()
        promedio = calcular_promedio(nombre)
        estudiantes[nombre] = {"notas": tuple(notas), "promedio": promedio}
        letra = input("Quires agregar otro estudiante? (S-SI - N-NO)")

def calcular_promedio(nombreEstudiante):
    estudiante = estudiantes.get(nombreEstudiante)
    if estudiante is None:
        return None
    notaEstudiante = estudiante.get("notas")
    if notaEstudiante is None:
        return None
    resultado = sum(notaEstudiante)
    return (resultado / len(notaEstudiante)) * 10
```

Resultado Consola:

```
{'Pedro': 
    {'notas': (7, 6, 9), 'promedio': None}, 
'Daniel': 
    {'notas': (10, 8, 6), 'promedio': None}}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Buen día, solo estás mostrando las funciones, por favor agrega la forma en que las estás usando, una prueba rápida de tu código con las notas `1,2,3` devuelve como promedio `20.0` por lo que funciona correctamente.

Comment: @HeytalePazguato listo, actualizado

Comment: Ah ya entendí, la formulación de la pregunta estaba mal, cuando dices devolver el promedio significa lo que devuelves al hacer `return` eso funciona correctamente, pero lo que no te funciona es "actualizar" el valor del promedio adentro del diccionario `estudiantes` deja redacto una respuesta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buen día,

Lo único que te hace falta es actualizar el diccionario `estudiantes` en la función `calcular_promedio`:

```
def calcular_promedio(nombreEstudiante):
    estudiante = estudiantes.get(nombreEstudiante)
    if estudiante is None:
        return None
    notaEstudiante = estudiante.get("notas")
    if notaEstudiante is None:
        return None
    resultado = sum(notaEstudiante)
    # Actualizar el promedio del estudiante
    estudiante['promedio'] = (resultado / len(notaEstudiante)) * 10
    # Devolver el promedio
    return estudiante['promedio']
```

Ejemplo de funcionamiento con un estudiante llamado "Prueba":

```
ingresar_estudiante()
print(estudiantes)
calcular_promedio('Prueba')
print(estudiantes)
```

Esto imprime:

```
Ingrese el nombre del estudiante:  Prueba
Ingrese las notas del estudiante Prueba (ingrese 'Q' para finalizar):  1
Ingrese las notas del estudiante Prueba (ingrese 'Q' para finalizar):  2
Ingrese las notas del estudiante Prueba (ingrese 'Q' para finalizar):  3
Ingrese las notas del estudiante Prueba (ingrese 'Q' para finalizar):  q
Quires agregar otro estudiante? (S-SI - N-NO) n
{'Prueba': {'notas': (1, 2, 3), 'promedio': None}}
{'Prueba': {'notas': (1, 2, 3), 'promedio': 20.0}}
```

Comment: Buenos días, muchas gracias por la respuesta lo pude solucionar :D, ahora entendí por qué era el None